# MySQL - Query: Best ranked price for article

Tags: mysql, subquery, rank

I have this query to find possible article prices:

```
SELECT MAX(ranking), prices.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        case when merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 100 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when invoice_merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 90 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when merchant_group_id IS NOT NULL then 80 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when whitelist_id IS NOT NULL then 700 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when season_id IS NOT NULL then 60 ELSE 0 END 
        AS ranking,
        price.id, price.article_id
        FROM (
            select  6587 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  6618 id, 4561 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  6985 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, NULL invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, 1 merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  7015 id, 1583 article_id, 1 merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9119 id, 4561 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9931 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9965 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9988 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, 1 whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  10460 id, 4561 article_id, 1 merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id 
            )price
) AS prices
GROUP BY prices.id
```

Results are

```
| MAX(ranking)  | ranking   | id    | article_id|
| 150           | 150       | 6587  | 1583      |
| 150           | 150       | 6618  | 4561      |
| 140           | 140       | 6985  | 1583      |
| 160           | 160       | 7015  | 1583      |
| 150           | 150       | 9119  | 4561      |
| 150           | 150       | 9931  | 1583      |
| 60            | 60        | 9965  | 1583      |
| 760           | 760       | 9988  | 1583      |
| 160           | 160       | 10511 | 4561      |
```

Now I need the both prices per article with highest rank:

```
| MAX(ranking)  | ranking   | id    | article_id|
| 760           | 760       | 9988  | 1583      |
| 160           | 160       | 10511 | 4561      |
```

What I tried, part #1

```
SELECT MAX(ranking), prices.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        case when merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 100 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when invoice_merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 90 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when merchant_group_id IS NOT NULL then 80 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when whitelist_id IS NOT NULL then 700 ELSE 0 END 
        AS ranking,
        price.id, price.article_id
        FROM (
            #subquery query
        )price
) AS prices
GROUP BY prices.article_id
```

results:

```
| MAX(ranking)  | ranking   | id    | article_id|
| 760           | 150       | 6587  | 1583      |
| 160           | 150       | 6618  | 4561      |
```

What I tried, part #2

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT MAX(ranking) max_ranking, prices.* FROM (
        SELECT 
            case when merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 100 ELSE 0 END 
            + case when invoice_merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 90 ELSE 0 END 
            + case when merchant_group_id IS NOT NULL then 80 ELSE 0 END 
            + case when whitelist_id IS NOT NULL then 700 ELSE 0 END 
            AS ranking,
            price.id, price.article_id
            FROM (
                #subquery query
            )price
    ) AS prices
    GROUP BY prices.id
) outer_prices
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY max_ranking desc
```

results

```
| max_ranking   | ranking   | id    | article_id|
| 150           | 150       | 6587  | 1583      |
| 150           | 150       | 6618  | 4561      |
```

I have tried some more solutions from stackoverflow, but nothing worked. Can anyone help?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I cannot post dozens of rows business code here which would not work. So I simulated the subquery result. Ok?

Comment: No. It's not OK. The linked answer is quite clear on these specific points.

Comment: I get it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MYSQL 8 or above try `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

[ROW_NUMBER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/)

```
select * from(
SELECT row_number() over(partition by id    , article_id order by ranking desc) rn, prices.* FROM (
    SELECT 
        case when merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 100 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when invoice_merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 90 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when merchant_group_id IS NOT NULL then 80 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when whitelist_id IS NOT NULL then 700 ELSE 0 END 
        AS ranking,
        price.id, price.article_id
        FROM (
            #subquery query
        )price
) AS prices
) as main
where rn=1
```

Below MYSQL 8 try this.

```
SELECT  RANKING,ID,ARTICLE_ID FROM (
    SELECT 
        case when merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 100 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when invoice_merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 90 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when merchant_group_id IS NOT NULL then 80 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when whitelist_id IS NOT NULL then 700 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when season_id IS NOT NULL then 60 ELSE 0 END 
        AS ranking,
        price.id, price.article_id
        FROM (
            select  6587 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  6618 id, 4561 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  6985 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, NULL invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, 1 merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  7015 id, 1583 article_id, 1 merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9119 id, 4561 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9931 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9965 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9988 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, 1 whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  10460 id, 4561 article_id, 1 merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id 
            )price
) AS prices
WHERE (ranking,article_id) IN (
(SELECT MAX(ranking),article_id FROM (
    SELECT 
        case when merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 100 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when invoice_merchant_id IS NOT NULL then 90 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when merchant_group_id IS NOT NULL then 80 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when whitelist_id IS NOT NULL then 700 ELSE 0 END 
        + case when season_id IS NOT NULL then 60 ELSE 0 END 
        AS ranking,
        price.id, price.article_id
        FROM (
            select  6587 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  6618 id, 4561 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  6985 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, NULL invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, 1 merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  7015 id, 1583 article_id, 1 merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9119 id, 4561 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9931 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, 1 invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9965 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  9988 id, 1583 article_id, null merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, 1 whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id union
            select  10460 id, 4561 article_id, 1 merchant_id, null invoice_merchant_id, null whitelist_id, null merchant_group_id, 1 season_id 
            )price
) AS prices
GROUP BY article_id)
)
```

Comment: I have Version 5.7

Comment: Worked, great job!

Comment: Try last one. I changed again this is more acurate without `group by` on the last query and using multiple IN clause. @Rawburner And could you also upvote please ?